# how to write data to usb HID terminal in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, usb

i wanna send some data on my **USB HID device** from my GUI Project in visual c++ , i have the **product Id** of my device as well as my **Vendor ID** but i want to connect to it sending some data. How can i do that?

Comment: @simchona: i wanna an example project to connect to the usb with its full source code so i can modify it as i want.

Comment: @Mohammed Yeah. I don't think you're going to get code without effort.

Answer (score 4):

The big guide to [HID](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm)

Not used it, but this might be useful [Class for USB Generic HID Communication](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Open_Source_Visual_C++_Class_for_USB_Generic_HID_Communication)

Comment: have you tried it ever before?

Comment: @GigaWatt: i tried it but unfortunately it didn't work